# unknown data in access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a problem in access. I have an access db with some tables, and I cant read the data stored in that and the characters are some squares. I tried many fonts but I can't read it yet.
can anybody help me?

Comment: What data type is the column?

Comment: its text. and it contains 31 characters which are days of a month. each character means an emplyee's group , or shift etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a website which converts characters to Unicode. each code is a kind of group number.

http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/unicode/converter.html
actually they inserted numbers as ascii codes :)